# Weird 404 URL Problem - domain name being placed at end of urls

Tags: php, mysql, customization

For some reason when doing crawl tests I'm finding pages with the domain name being tacked on the end and causing 404 errors. 
For example:  http://domainname.com/page-name/http://domainname.com

This is happening to all pages, posts and even category type

1. Site is in Wordpress
2. Using Yoast SEO plugin

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

For Example 
[image]

Comment: Try manually creating a sitemap using an external source such as [XML-Sitemaps.com](https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/). Also, I encountered a rare similar issue a few years ago that only happens when using GoDaddy for hosting. Is GoDaddy your hosting provider?

Comment: No, it's hosterpk domain provider. I am get 404 errors in webmaster tools.

Comment: You get the 404 error on your webmaster tools because the sitemap.xml was not properly created. I guess you created it using Yoast SEO plug-in. So, go to [XML-Sitemaps.com](https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/), generate one and compare it to the one that shows under http://yourdomainname.com/sitemap.xml

Comment: Nevermind, I missed read the post. The issue that you're facing can come from a lot of different places. You have to give more details and your WP URL if possible.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using for your crawl test and what is the domain? It would help to look at a page that has one of the broken links to see where it's coming from.

Comment: I got errors in webmaster tools.

Comment: It should show where the error is coming from though, do you have an example live URL to look at?

Comment: I am fixing the 404 by 301 redirects but it's not the permanent solution. whenever i add new category I got the 404 like this pattern in url.

Comment: It could be an issue with the theme, you'll need to share your website URL so I can see the HTML and tell you why it's most likely happening.

Comment: http://costproduct.com

Comment: Please see the question edited.

Comment: Your homepage at http://costproduct.com/ looks fine. The Google Webmasters though will display errors of broken pages coming from other websites though so the issue could be someone else is linking to your site incorrectly causing the error. Your screenshot shows the error page but not where it's linked from which is more important. As Jorge said the errors could actually be coming from a sitemap which is telling Google to index the broken page, definitely worth looking into.

Answer (score 0):

We have view this issue on elementor plugin, that have been duplicated pages above the button widget on "keep reading" element.

So, we remove this button and the issue go out. If you have this theme/plugin, try to remove the button from wordpress editing post.